# multiline string concatenation - ignore escape chars

Tags: javascript, string, special-characters

is there a suppress escape chars in Javascript similar to the @ in C# ?
I have to assemble a sting like below - however Im having problems with the multi-line layout and some of the characters in the string. How would one concatenate such a string in Javascript?

my attempt to concatenate my string in JAVASCRIPT:

```
  var idfTEXT_ROOM = "
    ! " + this.Name +"
    ! -------------
    Zone,
    " + this.Name + ",           !- Name
    " + this.DirRelNorth + ",    !- Direction of Relative North {deg}
    0,                       !- X Origin {m}
    0,                       !- Y Origin {m}
    0,                       !- Z Origin {m}
    1,                       !- Type
...
```

Of course like that it throws an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" error.

Comment: You would need to use newlines (\n) and probably tabs (\t), and figure out why on earth you would need such a string, and if there really aren't better approaches to the problem.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what language is "C# in Javascript".  From the looks of it, this is javascript but you're using tripple quotes?

Comment: Tripple quotes are always cool ?

Comment: What language is that? `!` comments and tripple quotes don't validate in JavaScript.

Comment: OK... would it be better to replace all the variables with some tag that I could later exchange with regex?

Comment: ok removed the """ - was just a desperate attempt to make it work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- \ - regular escape, if you need quote in your string just type \'
- \n - new line
- \t - tab

For multiline strings here are [different options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/how-to-create-multiline-strings) for you.

Im always using this method:

```
'Hello Javascript' + 
'world' +
'!!!' +
...
```

Comment: That would make the code span multiple lines, but not the string itself, but +1 for the escaped stuff ?

Comment: \n - new line.

Prev. example in one line string that returns multi-line code:
'Hello Javascript\nworld\n!!!'